# Running a build with multiple jobs (e. g.: -j8) seems to produce a race with Autotools-generated Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autotools, autoconf, automake

Consider I have a simple *Autotools* project consisting of just one source file (e. g.: [amhello](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Hello-World.html)).

Now, for some reason, despite there's a direct dependency between `all` and `check` targets in the generated `Makefile`, there seems to also be a race, so running

```
make -j8 all check
```

is likely to result in a build error:

```
make  all-recursive
Making check in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/build'
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/build/src'
/usr/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/src -I..     -g -O2 -MT test-test.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/test-test.Tpo -c -o test-test.o `test -f 'test.c' || echo '/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/src/'`test.c
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/build/src'
/usr/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/src -I..     -g -O2 -MT test-test.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/test-test.Tpo -c -o test-test.o `test -f 'test.c' || echo '/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/src/'`test.c
mv -f .deps/test-test.Tpo .deps/test-test.Po
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2   -o test test-test.o
mv -f .deps/test-test.Tpo .deps/test-test.Po
mv: cannot stat '.deps/test-test.Tpo': No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [GNUmakefile:369: test-test.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/build/src'
make[1]: *** [GNUmakefile:400: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/build'
make: *** [GNUmakefile:320: all] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/build/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/build'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/tmp.2E2WN3dwFg/build'
```

Naturally, running the same build using just a single *Make* job succeeds:

```
make -j1 all check
```

What *is* strange is that running

```
make -j8 check
```

always succeeds, too, resulting in the whole project being built.

1. How comes such a mature build system still produces `Makefile`'s with races?
2. And how `make check` is different from `make all check`, given that `all` is a pre-requisite of `check` anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question #1 is, I suppose, no one runs make with both `all` and `check` on the command line at the same time.  That's not a usual use model and so if there are problems, people haven't noticed.

As you point out, it's not useful since `make check` will build `all` first anyway, in the correct order.

I think that automake-generated makefiles always assume and require that one and only one "top-level" target is provided to the initial `make` invocation.

The answer to the second question I expect has to do with the fact that these makefiles are using recursive make.  That is, the top level make invocation does not have `check: all`.  It has `check: check-recursive` and it has `all: all-recursive`, so those rules can run in parallel.  Each one of them invokes a sub-make process and while the submake running `check-recursive` knows that it can't run the check in parallel with the `all` target *it* is running, the other submake running `all-recursive` doesn't know that some other make instance is also building `all` in that same directory.

Comment: I note also that Automake uses recursive `make` only when the user asks for it.  The amhello demo project that the OP referenced *does* ask for it, but this is not obligatory.  And of course, this all brings us squarely around into the territory of *Recursive Make Considered Harmful*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thanks! Had to search for a while before I found the link to the article: [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://web.archive.org/web/20150319074420/http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf).